# Creating QGIS plugin using comboBox

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I am trying to select an existing file in the panel in QGIS, however every time I put this code an error appears:

```py
layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
    layer_list = []
    for layer in layers:
        layer_list.append(layer.name())
    self.dlg.comboBox.addItems(layer_list)
```

Where the error is:

> "Unable to load output sadasda due to error calling classFactory ()
>   method
>
> IndentationError: unexpected indent"

where apparently can't compile the code:

```py
layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
```

Answer (score 1):

The error message is alerting you to an error in the indentation of your code.

This looks like QGIS 2 API code so I can't actually test it but the correct indentation for the code block you posted would be:

```
layers = self.iface.legendInterface().layers()
layer_list = []
for layer in layers:
    layer_list.append(layer.name())
self.dlg.comboBox.addItems(layer_list)
```

Comment: Thank you, I managed to solve.